# Automapper projections with Includable IQuerable

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper to project a database entity with include items to another domain entity

```
      IQueryable<DBTypeEntity> allItems = _dbContext.DBType.Include(e => e.A)
            .Include(e => e.B)
                .ThenInclude(e => e.C)
            .Include(e => e.D)
                .ThenInclude(ac => ac.E);
```

And using projections

```
              var result = allItems.ProjectTo<DBTypeDomain>(_typeMapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

Here are my mappings:

```
        CreateMap<DBTypeEntity, DBTypeDomain>()
            .ForMember(e => e.A, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(e => e.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.B))
            .ForMember(e => e.C, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.C))
            .ForMember(e => e.E, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.E))
            .ForMember(e => e.F, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<FResolver, ICollection<AssociatedFEntity>>(e => e.AssociatedFs))
            .ForMember(e => e.G, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.G));
```

Other types are straight property to property mappings with nothing special.
I have all the required profile mappings setup for the type mapper, however, I am getting a cryptic exception (Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression).
I am using EF Core 2.0 and Automapper 6.2.2

Any help please?

Comment: What does the mapping configuration look like? It probably contains methods that are not supported by `ProjectTo`. By the way, the projection is likely to cancel all `Includes`.

Comment: Projections and includes are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Oh Correct, one of my team members is using custom resolvers. Any idea how to workaround that?
Pls, how can I utilize automapper with IQueryable while still using projections? It was working fine when using IEnumerable with MapTo method, we needed to switch to IQuerable due to performance issues.

Comment: For any advice on work-arounds we obviously need to see the code.

Comment: Thanks, I added the profile mappings.

Comment: Show stack trace. And why not just remove the includes?

Comment: It's EF Core, so the Includes are needed. But the mapping has a resolver :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue.
Includes are no longer needed when using projections (as in Automapper Docs).
Custom resolver was replaced with a select statement from the set, the custom resolver was prohibiting using projections in AutoMapper for the IQueryable.

Comment: You might want to check the generated query, you don't need Include with EF6, but with EF Core, I hear things changed.

Comment: I checked the generated query via SQL profiler, and it does the inner joins with the required tables. And yes, includes were needed because we are using EF Core 2.0, however, I removed them after using AutoMapper projections.